Problem with Running KDE-Based Spectacle on Fedora 41 GNOME Wayland
I'm using Fedora 41 with GNOME on Wayland, and I want to use Spectacle, a KDE-based screenshot tool. In previous Fedora versions (39 and 40), I was able to use Spectacle on GNOME, and it worked fine even under Wayland (Fedora 39) and X11 (Fedora 40).
However, after upgrading to Fedora 41, I'm unable to get Spectacle to work properly. There is no longer an X11 option, and I am unsure how to proceed with Wayland.
In Fedora 39 and 40, KDE components were installed and Spectacle ran smoothly. But with Fedora 41, it seems like there's a compatibility issue under Wayland.
What should I do to make Spectacle work on Fedora 41 under GNOME on Wayland?
Things I've tried so far:

Installing kwin, kde-desktop didn't resolve the issue.

Any suggestions or solutions to get Spectacle working on Fedora 41 with Wayland would be greatly appreciated!
Installing kwin, kde-desktop didn't resolve the issue.

flameshot application works well.
